# TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined Laravel-mix

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

I'm developing an app on `laravel-mix` and it is working perfectly fine on our local system, We are sharing with team which is having windows and macos, but when we try to deploy our code on Ubuntu server it is not navigating and throwing us the error:

```
vue-router.esm.js?4dc1:2117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ab39ffc81e06137283e9:64)
at eval (login.vue?21d2:1)
at Object../node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!../nitseditor-frontend/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/pages/login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2379d9d6&scoped=true&lang=css& (ProjectPages-component.13725ab8fd677b7f258a.js:858)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ab39ffc81e06137283e9:64)
at eval (login.vue?5e7a:2)
at Object../node_modules/style-loader/index.js!./node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!../nitseditor-frontend/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/pages/login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2379d9d6&scoped=true&lang=css& (ProjectPages-component.13725ab8fd677b7f258a.js:924)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ab39ffc81e06137283e9:64)
at eval (login.vue?033a:1)
at Module../resources/pages/login.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=2379d9d6&scoped=true&lang=css& (ProjectPages-component.13725ab8fd677b7f258a.js:1846)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ab39ffc81e06137283e9:64)
```

My webpack.mix config looks something like this:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

const NitsRoutePlugins = require('./Webpack/NitsRoutePlugin');
const NitsComponentsPlugin = require('./Webpack/NitsComponentsPlugin');

mix.sass('node_modules/nitseditor-frontend/Assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/nits-assets/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [ require('autoprefixer'), tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
    })
    .js('node_modules/nitseditor-frontend/app.js', 'public/nits-assets/js')
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [

            ]
        },
        node: {
            fs: "empty"
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/',
            chunkFilename: 'nits-assets/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js',
        },
        resolve: {
            symlinks: false,
            extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
            alias: {
                NitsModels: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Models'),
                ProjectModels: path.resolve('./resources/models'),
                ProjectPages: path.resolve('./resources/pages'),
                NitsAdminPages: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Pages'),
                NitsComponents: path.resolve(__dirname, './Components'),
                Plugins: path.resolve('./plugins'),
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            new NitsRoutePlugins(),
            new NitsComponentsPlugin()
        ]
    })
    // .extract([
    //     'vue', 'axios', 'lodash', 'vue-router', 'vue-template-compiler', 'vuex'
    // ])
    .sourceMaps().version();
```

**Edit:**

I found out the problem whenever I'm mentioning any `style` elements inside my `vue-components` it is throwing me the error, also I'm having dynamic imports. I came to know through [this comment](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/79#issuecomment-549257406)

**Edit 2**

I want to use CKEditor5 and changed my webpack.mix.js to following:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
let path = require('path');
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

const NitsRoutePlugins = require('./Webpack/NitsRoutePlugin');
const NitsComponentsPlugin = require('./Webpack/NitsComponentsPlugin');
const NitsLayoutsPlugin = require('./Webpack/NitsLayoutsPlugin');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | CKEditor configuration
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Neccessary Webpack config files.
 |
 */
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin');
const CKEStyles = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils').styles;
const CKERegex = {
    svg: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
    css: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css/,
};

Mix.listen('configReady', webpackConfig => {
    const rules = webpackConfig.module.rules;
    const targetSVG = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;
    const targetFont = /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/;
    const targetCSS = /\.css$/;

    // exclude CKE regex from mix's default rules
    // if there's a better way to loop/change this, open to suggestions
    for (let rule of rules) {
        if (rule.test.toString() === targetSVG.toString()) {
            rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
        }
        else if (rule.test.toString() === targetFont.toString()) {
            rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
        }
        else if (rule.test.toString() === targetCSS.toString()) {
            rule.exclude = CKERegex.css;
        }
    }
});


mix.copy('node_modules/nitseditor-frontend/Assets/images', 'public/nits-assets/images')
    .sass('node_modules/nitseditor-frontend/Assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/nits-assets/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [ require('autoprefixer'), tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js') ],
    })
    .js(path.resolve('./resources/js/app.js'), 'public/nits-assets/js')
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: CKERegex.svg,
                    use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
                },
                {
                    test: CKERegex.css,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'style-loader',
                            options: {
                                singleton: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader',
                            options: CKEStyles.getPostCssConfig({
                                themeImporter: {
                                    themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                                },
                                minify: true
                            })
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        node: {
            fs: "empty"
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: '/',
            chunkFilename: 'nits-assets/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js',
        },
        resolve: {
            symlinks: false,
            extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
            alias: {
                NitsModels: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Models'),
                ProjectModels: path.resolve('./resources/models'),
                ProjectPages: path.resolve('./resources/pages'),
                NitsAdminPages: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Pages'),
                NitsComponents: path.resolve(__dirname, './Components'),
                Plugins: path.resolve('./plugins'),
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            new NitsRoutePlugins(),
            new NitsComponentsPlugin(),
            new NitsLayoutsPlugin(),
            new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({language: 'en', additionalLanguages: 'all'})
        ]
    })
    // .extract([
    //     'vue', 'axios', 'lodash', 'vue-router', 'vue-template-compiler', 'vuex'
    // ])
    // .nitsEditor()
    .sourceMaps().version();
```

Now it is again showing me same error, not able to import my CKEditor component:

```
<template>
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
    import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
    // import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

    import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
    import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
    import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
    import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
    import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';


    export default {
        name: "NitsCkeditor",
        components: {
            // Use the <ckeditor> component in this view.
            ckeditor: CKEditor.component
        },
        data() {
            return {
                editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorConfig: {
                    plugins: [
                        EssentialsPlugin,
                        BoldPlugin,
                        ItalicPlugin,
                        LinkPlugin,
                        ParagraphPlugin
                    ],

                    toolbar: {
                        items: [
                            'bold',
                            'italic',
                            'link',
                            'undo',
                            'redo'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

It is showing me this error:

[image: Console error]

Help me out with this.

Comment: DId you solve this?

Comment: @FernandoTorres may be this can help: https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/2376